# Selenium Select option from suggest box

Tags: selenium

I must test an application that you type 3 letters in a text box and pick an option from a generated list. 
How can I  do this with Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1):

That generated list can be implemented a number of different ways. The important thing to understand is that JavaScript will be executed as you are typing which will in turn update the DOM, modifying the HTML on the page. In order to get the HTML of the generated list, you would need to pull up the page in a browser, type in 3 letters and then while the list is displayed use the developer tools for that browser (or Firebug for Firefox) to view the HTML. It is then just a matter of identifying the element by either ID, or some other method and interacting with it, probably with the `Click` method.

Comment: Oh, another possibly simpler solution would be to use the recorder to record the scenario and use whatever method of identifying the element the code from the recorded scenario uses.